# Reverse words not individual characters in a cell Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have come across a formula that `reverses text` like this

`sesrever txet`

I am however trying to reverse whole words not just individual characters. So that `reverse text` becomes `text reverse.`

I want the words separated by space to change the order so that the 1st becomes the last.

`last the becomes 1st`.

Text may contain numbers but the space is what I need to use to reverse.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet or formula you found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this with a phrase in cell A2.

```
=JOIN(" ",SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2," ")),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2," "))),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to try out a Google Apps Script solution; in particular a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

```
function reverse(text) {
  return text.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
}
```

Save the latter to the script editor ( Tools => Script editor) and then you can use `reverse(text)` in your sheet:

[image: solution]

Comment: exactly the same as mine. `cellValue.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');` but recently found out that what he wanted was formula so I didn't bother posting mine haha

Comment: feel free to post alternative solutions even if another one has been accepted. In this way, you enrich a particular post :) @NaziA

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=JOIN(" ", INDEX(SORT({FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1, " ")), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(A1, " "))))}, 2, ),, 1))
```

[image]

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ", SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(MID(SPLIT(A1, " "), 
 SORT(ROW($A$1:INDIRECT("A"&LEN(A1))), 1, ), 1),,9^9), " ", )))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, {A1, SPLIT(A1, " ")}, 
 TRANSPOSE(SORT(ROW(A2:A), 1, )), ))))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to reverse when you have a mixture of text and numbers like this ```1 [2] This Text``` and have the numbers coming after the text part? So that the output is ```This Text [2] 1```. Please let me know if this requires a new question. I'll oblige.

Comment: @maryongubo sure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZgh5.png